# How to use mod_rewrite with Zend Framework?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I've just deployed a new site using Zend Framework. Due to the popularity of my tutorials I'd like to redirect any request for a tutorial to the relevant page on the new site. So far this is what I've got:

URL before Rewrite: http://neranjara.org/tutorials/?tid=56

URL after Rewrite: http://neranjara.org/article/id/56

The .htaccess file I'm attempting to use looks like this:

```
  $ cat html/.htaccess
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule tutorials/\?tid=(.*)$ /article/id/$1 [R=301]
  RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|xml|phps)$ index.php
```

But this rule is not matching any URLs ... :'(

Does any one see a problem here?

Answer (score 3):

The query string (the parameters passed to your file) won't be in the RewriteRule.

Taken from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule:

> The Pattern will not be matched
>   against the query string. Instead, you
>   must use a RewriteCond with the
>   %{QUERY_STRING} variable. You can,
>   however, create URLs in the
>   substitution string, containing a
>   query string part. Simply use a
>   question mark inside the substitution
>   string, to indicate that the following
>   text should be re-injected into the
>   query string. When you want to erase
>   an existing query string, end the
>   substitution string with just a
>   question mark. To combine a new query
>   string with an old one, use the [QSA]
>   flag.

You have two possibilities here:

1. Remove your first RewriteRule and do the verification in your index.php instead before continuing to your framework. The initial query should be available in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or something like that. So verify if it's **tutorials**, take the **tid** parameter and then go on with a redirection:

   ```
   header("Location: http://http://neranjara.org/article/id/$id");
   exit();
   ```
2. Use RewriteCond with %{QUERY_STRING} instead as stated in the Apache documentation. This solution is discussed in thread like [this one](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3752570.htm).

**// Edit:**

Have a look at [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403703/modrewrite-with-zend-framework#406079) who was kind enough to detail the solution using QUERY_STRING. This is probably what you'll want to use. Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your previous entry:

```
  $ cat html/.htaccess
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule tutorials/\?tid=(.*)$ /article/id/$1 [R=301]
  RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|xml|phps)$ index.php
```

I'd suggest using this instead:

```
  $ cat html/.htaccess
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tid=([^&]*)
  RewriteRule tutorials/ /article/id/%1 [R=301, L]

  RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|xml|phps)$ index.php [L]
```

BTW, this is just an example of the many things you could do using the `QUERY_STRING` variable in mod_rewrite. My vote goes to 'lpfavreau' since this is option #2 from their answer.

Answer (score -1):

Zend uses all the htaccess power that htaccess can deliver so theres a very handy(chainable and interesting and not very well documented) method to achive this in the bootstrap!

You must use the Zend Router in your bootstrap (index.php). Probably something like: (this would be foo.com/article/23

> $router =
>   $frontController->getRouter();
>
> $route = new
>   Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
>       'article/:id',
>       array('id' => 1) ); $router->addRoute('article', $route);

More info [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)